# bootstrap toggle button with flag

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a bootstrap toggle button with flag for language selector FR/AR
when I chose FR I will get url 1
when I chaise AR i will get url 2
something like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: Give examples of what you've tried.. This is a place to help you solve problems, not to create entire solutions

Comment: You need to try something before asking.

Comment: What if you toggle both of them on?

Comment: Use the bootstrap toggle and put a background-image on it: http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/. However I don't see how a multi-toggle can work when only one selection can be valid

Comment: i found solution
https://jsfiddle.net/dtvdqjb8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<div class='onDiv'></div>" data-off="<div class='offDiv'></div>" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="default" name="test" checked />
```

css:

```
.onDiv{
  background:url('http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/pix/unionjack2.jpg');
  background-size:contain;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:36px;
  width:72px;
}
.offDiv{
  background:url('http://www.mapsofworld.com/images/world-countries-flags/italy-flag.gif');
  background-size:contain;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:36px;
  width:72px;
}
```

What I did, was to create a bootstrap toggle and set a flag as background for each one of it's states (on/off)

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dtvdqjb8/

Hope that helps

Comment: Thhhhhhhhhhhhhx <3